# Passing multiple checkbox items to PHP file using JSON and querying a DB

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to pass multiple checkboxes with different values to a PHP script that will run a search against my database for the values that are selected.

The HTML form is as follows:

```
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords"  value="option1" title="option1" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords"  value="option2" title="option2" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords"  value="option3" title="option3" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords"  value="option4" title="option4" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="search" /></li>
```

The javascript code to pass this to my PHP file is:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").click(function()
        {           
        $.post("parser.php", 
                    { 
                        keywords: $(".keywords:checked").val() 
                    }, 
                   function(data)
                   {        
                        $.each(data, function()
                        {   
                            $("div#result").append("<li class='arrow'><a href='parser.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a></li>");
                        });

                        $("div#jsonContent").show();

                    }, 
            "json");

        });

    });
    </script>
```

In parser.php I then take the incoming keyword, and search the database:

```
$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET["keywords"]);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keyworddb WHERE keywords LIKE '%". $keywords ."%' ");
$arr = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
{
$arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"] );
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This is all great, it runs through without any errors except:

1) In firebug it's sending over the selected checkbox value, though not the multiple checkboxes. It only uses the first checkbox value if multiple checkboxes selected.

2) Despite that it returns all entries to the table :( no matter what is selected.

Any help appreciated.

#### Update:

I've made the chanegs suggested:

```
            <form id="findkeywords">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords[]"  value="option1" title="option 1" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords[]"  value="option2" title="option 2" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords[]"  value="option3" title="option 3" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="keywords[]"  value="option4" title="option 4" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="search" /></li>
            </ul>
            </form>
```

The Javascript has been changed to:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").click(function()
        {            
        $.post("parser.php", 
                       { 
                           keywords: $("form#findkeywords").serialize() 
                       }, 
                   function(data)
                   {        
                        $.each(data, function()
                        {    
                            $("div#result").append("<li class='arrow'><a href='parser.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a></li>");
                        });

                        $("div#jsonContent").show();

                    }, 
            "json");

        });

    });
```

I haven't made any additional changes to the php file yet as I just want to make sure this is actually sending the data across. But in FireBug it doesn't appear to be sending anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem using `.val()` the way you are is it is passing an array to the data, to do that you would have to use a JSON library to 'stringify' it to send to your php.  If you use `.serialize()` there would be no need to try and parse it on the other side, it will have the data emulate regular serialized form data.

Personally, I would name your checkbox group as an array, and the just serialize the checkboxes as a form.

**Form:**

```
<form id="checkboxes">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]"  value="option1" title="option1" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]"  value="option2" title="option2" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]"  value="option3" title="option3" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]"  value="option4" title="option4" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="search" /></li>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").click(function()
    {           
        $.post("parser.php", $("form#checkboxes").serialize(), 
        function(data)
        {        
            $.each(data, function()
            {   
                $("div#result").append("<li class='arrow'><a href='parser.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a></li>");
            });
            $("div#jsonContent").show();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You will then need to treat `$_POST['keywords']` as an `Array`

You can access them with a simple `foreach`

```
foreach($_POST['keywords'] as $keyword) {
    echo $keyword;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm just learning jQuery/JSON so bare with me. I've made changes to the code and run it. I'm watching how the script is running in Firebug and there doesn't appear to be anything posted from the script. I would've expected something like:

keywords[]=option1&keywords[]option2&keywords[]=option3

or something similar?

Comment: Well without seeing the changes you made I can't help, I would say make sure you are wraping your checkboxes in a unique form, and you are serializing the form, not the checkboxes.

Comment: I'll answer in a full question with changes :)

Comment: also, your checkboxes do not have "names", they need to have `name="keywords[]"` not `class`

Comment: Doh, I see what I did there... just have to figure out how to explode json encoded arrays and use it against my database search.

Comment: sounds like a new question ;)

Comment: Heh, now that you mention it... i'm looking through some stuff online and assuming the syntax is something like

//$decode = json_decode($_GET['keywords[]']);

or am I totally out?

Comment: with my solution you don't have to worry about JSON, it is posting serialized form data so `$_POST['keywords']` is actually already an array (as i noted at the end of my answer).

Comment: Right, but does that not have to be unserialized?

I'm trying to run through the serialized data and extract whatever checkboxes have been checked to run against the database.

Something like this perhaps?

$keywords = unserialize($_POST['keywords']); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keyworddb WHERE keyword LIKE '%". $keywords ."%' ");

Comment: no, `$_POST['keywords']` is an array, so each checkbox will be its own array value.  And no, it is a horrible idea to inject user input directly into a sql command.

Comment: Okay, can I access the different results directly?

Or should I write a for loop like:

for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['keywords']); $i++){
}

I'm still a little lost (noob) on how to get the different options and values out of the array into individual variables to search against the DB.

Comment: no reason to write a full `for` loop, just do a foreach.  updated answer to reflect. You might consider upvoting my answer for all this additional attention.... ;)

Comment: Cheers mate! I haven't got enough karma to upvote... i'd definitely upvote if I could.