# Extracting JQuery POST parameters in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to pass a group of checkboxes to PHP using JQuery. I am using the code from [Passing multiple checkbox items to PHP file using JSON and querying a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880958/passing-multiple-checkbox-items-to-php-file-using-json-and-querying-a-db) Should I post this under that question?

The checkboxes are one for each day in the month in a calendar. Values are integer days of the month

```
<td><input name="check[]" value="4" type="checkbox">4</td>
<td><input checked="yes" name="check[]" value="7" type="checkbox">7</td>
```

The checkboxes are within a table in a form.

```
<form id="checkboxes">
<table id="calendarId" class="calendar">
```

I use Jquery to pass the checkboxes to PHP:

```
   $("#calendarId").load($.post("calendar.php",{check: $("form#checkboxes").serialize()}));
```

Firebug shows that a list of checked boxes is in the post parameters. The two days I checked to generate this example were 7 and 21 which are discernible in the code.

```
check   check%5B%5D=7&check%5B%5D=21
Source
check=check%255B%255D%3D7%26check%255B%255D%3D21
```

My problem is that I am unable to extract these values in PHP.

```
parse_str($_POST['check'], $checkboxes);
```

returns an empty string, as does looping over the POST array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
    $test .= $key . "; " . $value . "; ";
}
```

Trying to loop over $_POST['check'] generates an error which I assume means that $_POST['check'] is empty.

The complete page is at http://www.genomics.liv.ac.uk/shereMuseum/calendar1.html

I have also tried to pack the checkboxes into a data structure "checkboxes" before posting:

```
        var checkboxes = new Array();
        $("input[name='check[]']:checked").each(function(){checkboxes.push($(this).val());});
```

or

```
        $.each($("input[name='check[]']:checked"),function() {
                checkboxes.push($(this).val());
        });
```

But then Firebug reports the POST parameters as:

```
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
Source
undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.
Harry

Comment: "Trying to loop over $_POST['check'] generates an error which I assume means that $_POST['check'] is empty." Try var_dump($_POST); in your PHP and see what you're actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this:
http://files.nette.org/109/jquery.ajaxform.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using $('#calendarId').load(...), but have you tried doing it like

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'calendar.php',
    data: $('#checkboxes').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        // handle the response here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to Tom who found the answer.

The data could be extracted from $checkboxes as a two dimensional array:

    parse_str($_POST['check'], $checkboxes);
    $firstElement = $checkboxes['check'][0];

I was also trying to use the same method to collect the return values of the POST from the jquery as had been working for GET. The correct jQuery command was:

      $("#calendarId").load($.post("calendar.php",{check: $("form#checkboxes").serialize()}, function(data) { $("#calendarId").html(data); }));
         
which replaces everything in calendarId with the contents of the return value;